# Use a domain like name to access a test site instead of an IP address

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm currently testing a few websites on Ubuntu Server installed on Oracle VM Virtual Box on a Windows 11 machine.

I need to type an IP address to access these sites (eg: 192.168.xxx.xxx).

Is it possible to use something like a domain name to access them instead of using an IP address? Like mysite1.com, mysite2.com etc.

I'm not using domain names booked on godaddy or some place like that. Just names for local testing. How can it be done in this scenario? Everything is installed on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Add your sites to /etc/hosts file like this:

```
192.168.... mysite.domain
```

Comment: I did this and restarted the server, but I get taken to the actual site that is online. I used `192.168.***.*** example.com` in the host file, but site `example.com` gets loaded. Not my local test site...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go to /etc/hosts and apply IP you are using and the domain name you want:

Example.

Open with:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

apply:

```
192.168.x.x mysite.com
```

And restart server.

TRY CLEAN CACHE

```
sudo apt-get install nscd
```

AND NOW

```
sudo service nscd restart
```

or

```
sudo service dns-clean
```

Comment: I did this and restarted the server, but I get taken to the actual site that is online. I used `192.168.***.*** example.com` in the host file, but site `example.com` gets loaded. Not my local test site...

Comment: I edited my answer try with this after put the other on /etc/hosts.

Comment: This doesn't work either. Mind you, Ubuntu Server is on Oracle Virtual Box which is on a Windows 11 machine.

Answer (score 0):

To restate your setup, you have one Ubuntu server guest VM (in VirtualBox) running on Windows 11.  Because you mentioned the 192.168.x.x IP range I will assume the guest VM is on a "bridged" vbox network adapter that any device on your local network can ping.  I also have to assume the IP address(es) you are using are successfully connecting you from your Windows 11 host to your Ubuntu guest.  Is all this correct?  Does your VM have a desktop and a web application that can reach popular sites on the internet?  Does the Ubuntu OS use DHCP or a static IP assignment?

The short answer is yes, you can use domain names instead of IP addresses.  If you are not successful connecting to the IP address, switching to domain names will not help you.  You have to have all the network dependencies satisfied first.
To choose a domain name for testing;

You should take a look at RFC 6761.  Specifically at secion 6; 6.1 - 6.5
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761.html

```
.in-addr.arpa.
        10.in-addr.arpa.  21.172.in-addr.arpa.   26.172.in-addr.arpa.
    16.172.in-addr.arpa.  22.172.in-addr.arpa.   27.172.in-addr.arpa.
    17.172.in-addr.arpa.  30.172.in-addr.arpa.   28.172.in-addr.arpa.
    18.172.in-addr.arpa.  23.172.in-addr.arpa.   29.172.in-addr.arpa.
    19.172.in-addr.arpa.  24.172.in-addr.arpa.   31.172.in-addr.arpa.
    20.172.in-addr.arpa.  25.172.in-addr.arpa.  168.192.in-addr.arpa.
```

```
.test.
.localhost.
.invalid.
.example.com.
.example.net.
.example.org.
```

You may have to create/modify the \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file that Windows uses to intercept asking DNS for IP/host mapping.  If you are using a linux/unix client, the /etc/nsswitch.conf AND /etc/hosts files could override DNS for you.  This may or may not be in the same location on Windows 11  but as of Windows 10 21H2 it was still there.